# Manipulate The Currenly Edited Row in a grid view

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to make the editing functionality of gridview a bit smarter.

as first step I want that **when I press Edit for a line**
all the columns with `DateTime` data will have a datepicker instead of textbox
seems that my try is able only to edit the row behind and not the currently displayed edit items.

My goal is to change the date columns in the row I am editing to datepickers.

```
protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    var row = ((GridView)sender).Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells;

    for (int i = 0; i < row.Count; i++)
    {
        DateTime dtDate;
        var res = DateTime.TryParse(row[i].Text, out dtDate);
        if (res)
        {
            DatePickerControl.DatePicker text = new DatePickerControl.DatePicker();
            text.CalendarDate = dtDate;
            row[i].Controls.Clear();
            row[i].Controls.Add(text);
        }
    }
}
```

but it seems it edits the row behind, how can I make it edit what I am curretly editing?

Comment: Don't you need to do something with the Current Row / Cell of your GridView1 Control
something like the following 

int i = GridView1.CurrentRow.Index + 1;
Gridview1.CurrentCell = GridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even if the approach is different and possibly a little bit too simplistic for your scenario, I suggest you to use the `<asp:TemplateField />` in order to customize the edit item template (see below). Of course, you might also want to replace the `<asp:Calendar />` control that I used with the your custom `DatePickerControl.DatePicker` control.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <EditItemTemplate>
                <asp:Calendar runat="server" SelectedDate='<%# Eval("Date") %>'></asp:Calendar>
            </EditItemTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Date") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

**[UPDATE]**

There is also the possibility for you to create the columns dynamically. Please check the code below:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        GridView1.AutoGenerateEditButton = true;

        DataTable dataSource = new DataTable();
        dataSource.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
        dataSource.Columns.Add("Date1", typeof(DateTime));
        dataSource.Columns.Add("Date2", typeof(DateTime));
        dataSource.Rows.Add(1, DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(1));
        dataSource.Rows.Add(2, DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2), DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3));

        GridView1.Columns.Clear();
        foreach (DataColumn column in dataSource.Columns)
        {
            if (column.DataType == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                var templateColumn = new TemplateField();
                templateColumn.EditItemTemplate = new AddTemplateToGridView(ListItemType.EditItem, column.ColumnName);
                templateColumn.ItemTemplate = new AddTemplateToGridView(ListItemType.Item, column.ColumnName);
                templateColumn.HeaderText = column.ColumnName;
                GridView1.Columns.Add(templateColumn);
            }
            else
            {
                var dataBoundColumn = new BoundField();
                dataBoundColumn.DataField = column.ColumnName;
                dataBoundColumn.HeaderText = column.ColumnName;
                GridView1.Columns.Add(dataBoundColumn);
            }
        }

        GridView1.DataSource = dataSource;
        GridView1.DataBind();

    }

    public class AddTemplateToGridView : ITemplate
    {

        ListItemType _type;
        string _colName;

        public AddTemplateToGridView(ListItemType type, string colname)
        {
            _type = type;
            _colName = colname;
        }

        public void InstantiateIn(Control container)
        {
            switch (_type)
            {
                case ListItemType.Item:

                    Label l = new Label();
                    l.DataBinding += l_DataBinding;
                    container.Controls.Add(l);

                    break;
                case ListItemType.EditItem:

                    Calendar calendar = new Calendar();
                    calendar.DataBinding += l_DataBinding;
                    container.Controls.Add(calendar);

                    break;
            }
        }

        void l_DataBinding(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow container;
            object dataValue;
            switch (sender.GetType().ToString())
            {
                case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.Label":
                    Label label = (Label)sender;
                    container = (GridViewRow)label.NamingContainer;
                    dataValue = DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, _colName);
                    if (dataValue != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        label.Text = dataValue.ToString();
                    }
                    break;
                //use the DatePickerControl.DatePicker type instead of calendar
                case "System.Web.UI.WebControls.Calendar":
                    Calendar calendar = (Calendar)sender;
                    container = (GridViewRow)calendar.NamingContainer;
                    dataValue = DataBinder.Eval(container.DataItem, _colName);
                    if (dataValue != DBNull.Value)
                    {
                        calendar.SelectedDate = (DateTime)dataValue;
                        calendar.VisibleDate = (DateTime)dataValue;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }

}
```

Comment: alex my problem is that the grid should work with ANY table. I have no idea what table I will be provided.

Comment: Ok, then dynamically declare and add your `TemplateField`s in the code behind file. But maybe if you do that, it's the opposite of "simplistic" :)

Comment: Here's a good example: [Dynamically creating TemplateField for GridView](http://forums.asp.net/t/1001702.aspx/1)

Answer (score 2):

I'd say this is the wrong approach, you shouldn't be faffing with Control types at run-time  Your datagrid column should be of a datepicker type when the datagrid was built.

Unfortunately MS don't provide one, fortunately they do provide the framework to allow you do so:

You need 3 things, a new 1) `DataGridViewColumn`, a new 2)`DataGridViewTextBoxCell` and finally the actual 3) DateTimePicker editing control.

1:

```
public class DataGridViewCalendarColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
    public DataGridViewCalendarColumn()
        : base(new DataGridViewCalendarCell())
    { }

    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get { return base.CellTemplate; }
        set
        {
            // Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CalendarCell.
            if (value != null &&
                !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(DataGridViewCalendarCell)))
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a DataGridViewCalendarCell");

            base.CellTemplate = value;

        }
    }
}
```

2:

```
public class DataGridViewCalendarCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    public DataGridViewCalendarCell()
        : base()
    {
        this.Style.Format = "d";    //short date style
    }

    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        //set the value of the editing control to the current cell value
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);

        DataGridViewCalendarControl ctl = DataGridView.EditingControl as DataGridViewCalendarControl;

        //use default value if Value is null
        if (this.Value == null || this.Value == DBNull.Value)
            ctl.Value = (DateTime) this.DefaultNewRowValue;
        else
            ctl.Value = (DateTime) this.Value;
    }

    public override Type EditType
    {
        get
        {
            //return the type of control this cell uses
            return typeof(DataGridViewCalendarControl);
        }
    }

    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get
        {
            //return the type of the value that this cell contains
            return typeof(DateTime);
        }
    }

    public override object DefaultNewRowValue
    {
        get
        {
            //use today's date as the default value
            return DateTime.Now;
        }
    }
}
```

3:

```
public class DataGridViewCalendarControl : DateTimePicker, IDataGridViewEditingControl
    {
        private DataGridView dataGridView;
        private bool hasValueChanged = false;
        int rowIndex;

        public DataGridViewCalendarControl()
        {
            this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
        }

        protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs eventargs)
        {
            //Notify the DataGridView that the value has changed
            hasValueChanged = true;
            this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);

            base.OnValueChanged(eventargs);
        }

        #region IDataGridViewEditingControl Members

        public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
        {
            this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
            this.CalendarForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor;
            this.CalendarMonthBackground = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor;
        }

        public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
        {
            get { return dataGridView; }
            set { dataGridView = value; }
        }

        public object EditingControlFormattedValue
        {
            get { return this.Value.ToShortDateString(); }
            set
            {
                if (value is String)
                    try
                    {
                        this.Value = DateTime.Parse((String) value);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        this.Value = DateTime.Now;
                    }
            }
        }

        public int EditingControlRowIndex
        {
            get { return rowIndex; }
            set { rowIndex = value; }
        }

        public bool EditingControlValueChanged
        {
            get { return hasValueChanged; }
            set { hasValueChanged = value; }
        }

        public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(Keys keyData, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
        {
            //the DateTimePicker needs to handle the keys
            switch (keyData & Keys.KeyCode)
            {
                case Keys.Left:
                case Keys.Right:
                case Keys.Up:
                case Keys.Down:
                case Keys.Home:
                case Keys.End:
                case Keys.PageUp:
                case Keys.PageDown:
                    return true;

                default:
                    return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
            }
        }

        public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
        {
            get { return base.Cursor; }
        }

        public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
        {
            return EditingControlFormattedValue;
        }

        public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
        {
            //nowt needs doing...
        }

        public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
        {
            get { return false; }
        }
```

Then in the form's Load event:

```
eventDateDataGridViewCalendarColumn = new DataGridViewCalendarColumn();
eventDateDataGridViewCalendarColumn.DataPropertyName = "EventDate";
eventDateDataGridViewCalendarColumn.HeaderText = "Date";
//we've created the column, now insert it into the right location (after the ID and UserID)
this.tSEventsDataGridView.Columns.Insert(2, eventDateDataGridViewCalendarColumn);

//remove the original TextBox EventDate column added via VS
this.tSEventsDataGridView.Columns.RemoveAt(3);
```

where `eventDateDataGridViewCalendarColumn` is a `private DataGridViewCalendarColumn`.  That's it, we've got nowt in any edit events.

Now this works for us, but as always with random samples found on the 'net, use at your own risk!

Comment: forgot to mention, that you should be able to see that this allows for the grid to contain any type of control, in-built or something you create.

Comment: is there any change you have a small sample project for this?

Comment: i agreed with @cjb110 and i have done the solution some thing like this but i have done it in vc++ for sure there are some bugs with .NET controls, Always long paths take time but responsible.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your issue is with `e.NewEditIndex` not being the correct value because the `RowEditing` event is fired *before* the row is actually put into edit mode. This means that the value of `e.NewEditIndex` will be the index of whatever row you last edited. If I had to guess, I'd say you were iterating through the rows sequentially, so it was pure coincidence that you were always modifying "the row behind."

From the documentation, it appears you can get the index of the currently selected row by accessing the `GridView.SelectedIndex` property. If the row is going to be selected before being edited:

You could change: `var row = ((GridView)sender).Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells;`

to: `var row = ((GridView)sender).Rows[(GridView)sender.SelectedIndex].Cells;`

You could also explore putting the row into edit mode manually with the `SetEditRow` method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.seteditrow.aspx

Either way, you will need to know the index of the row that you're currently on prior to calling the `RowEditing` event, or force the row into edit mode using `SetEditRow` method, which will propagate the correct index into the `RowEditing` event.

Good luck.

Comment: 'e.NewEditIndex' IS the value of the row currently been edited. that can be confirmed by simple trial and error

Selected Index is the index of the row chosen using the 'select' command. you are totally on the wrong way.
thanks for trying though.

Comment: Alright, I guess I comprehended the documentation wrong. If that's the case then, can't you just increment the index by 1 to get the correct row?

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void GridView1_RowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    bindgrid();
    var row = ((GridView)sender).Rows[e.NewEditIndex].Cells;

    for (int i = 0; i < row.Count; i++)
    {
        DateTime dtDate;
        var res = DateTime.TryParse(row[i].Text, out dtDate);
        if (res)
        {
            Calendar cal = new Calendar();
            cal.SelectedDate = dtDate;
            cal.VisibleDate = dtDate;
            cal.DataBind();
            //DatePickerControl.DatePicker text = new DatePickerControl.DatePicker();
            //text.CalendarDate = dtDate;
            row[i].Controls.Clear();
            row[i].Controls.Add(cal);
        }
    }

}
```

try this

Comment: its  just simple function i wrote to bind the grid,in case of you ,you must have this already.