# How do I transform a column in datagridview similar to a Win Os time picker?

Tags: c#, custom-datetimepicker

I have no Idea how do I start with it because all we have in the designer of datagridview is buttons,textboxes n combo boxes.

I want to give it a feel such as :
when the user clicks on the column the column should show a time picker only and not the date picker.
 I have actually a code running that validates the textbox if it contains a valid time or not but it has a lot of bugs that the user can get through.
And moreover the user wont feel at home while manually typing in all the digits.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to 'create' the DateTimePicker column and then add it to the datagrid.
See the following SO question: [Manipulate The Currenly Edited Row in a grid view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14012429/manipulate-the-currenly-edited-row-in-a-grid-view/14236110#14236110)